# Attempted to call method "getDoctrine" on class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have been trying to add multiple cars to a user but I always get this error,
I have been searching the web for an answer for 2 days and I'm still stuck
P.S.: I'm new in Symfony and doctrine

```php
<?php

namespace CarsBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CarsController extends Controller
{

    public function addCarsAction($iduser,$carName,$carPrice,$carVIN)
    {
        $cars = new cars();
        $cars->setPic('')
             ->setName($carName)
             ->setModle(Null)
             ->setPrice($carPrice)
             ->setVin($carVIN)
             ->setIdUser($iduser);
        //$this->forward('acme.controller.tagclass:ParseWebsite',array($categoryid));
            $em1 = $this->forward('app.cars_controller')
                        ->getDoctrine()->getManager()
                        ->getRepository('OBCarsTest1Bundle:cars')
                        ->persist($cars)
                        ->flush();
        }
        public function addCarsToUserAction()
        {       
            $this->addCarsAction(1,'bmw',45000,'o102384');
            //$this->addCarsAction(1,'mercedes',53000,'o224384');
            //$this->addCarsAction(1,'nisan',25000,'o686495');
            //$this->addCarsAction(2,'golf',44000,'o659826');
            //$this->addCarsAction(2,'toyota',23000,'o255325');

            //test if it works
            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('OBCarsTest1Bundle:cars');      
            $cars = $repository->findOneById(3);

            return new Response('Created cars : \n '.$cars);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-thinking it just use:
`$em1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` instead of

`$em1 = $this->forward('app.cars_controller')->getDoctrine()->getManager()`

and for persistency assuming you have a propper ORM mapping you just need to add:
`$em1->persist($cars); $em1->flush();` and it will save it in the database

Comment: Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given

Comment: In order to answer your next question I need to look at the code, cause without the ORM mapping it's pointless to discuss. You need to update the question with the mapping.